# Anisotropic filtering and multisample anti-aliasing

Tags: antialiasing, supersampling

Anisotropic filtering and multisample anti-aliasing both imply supersampling.

In [EWA](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ph/texfund/texfund.pdf) and (derived) [Feline](http://watkins.cs.queensu.ca/~jstewart/454/notes/WRL-99-1.pdf) AF algorithms a non-uniform weighted average is used. But in case of MSAA not. Why this is the case? Isn't it better to use weighted average in case of MSAA?